# Changing default or bulk to show Thousands Separators in ArcGIS Pro attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, display

I am creating a Map Series in ArcGIS Pro, and have a number of dynamic text elements populated by numeric fields in my map series layer.  The default for numeric values appears to be to not use thousands separators, however I would like to see them, at least in my dynamic text elements.

[image]

Now I know I can change the Number Format from the attribute table, by right-clicking a field and then clicking the ellipsis next to "Numeric", and checking on *Show thousands separators*

[image]

[image]

[image]

But this only changes it for the one field.  I would like this to be the default setting in my project, or at least be able to change it in bulk for the multiple fields I need to display.

How can I change all my (selected) fields to show thousands separators?

I have looked through the text element formatting options and can't see anything in there either.

Comment: Maybe changing Windows regional settings will work?

Comment: @FelixIP good suggestion that I hadn't thought of, unfortunately it appears my regional settings already have thousands separated